# CSS priority border-box

Tags: css, css-tables, border-box

CSS victim is here

Why is the following style:

```
.slider-menu .menu-app-container .non-menu .main-container * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

prevailing over this one:

```
.table > thead > tr > td > input, 
.table > tbody > tr > td > input, 
.table > tfoot > tr > td > input {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

?

Comment: Because the first selector has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than the second one.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it has a greater [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) (0,0,4,0) = 40 than the other (0,0,1,4) = 14

There are also online specificity calculators available, such as [this one](http://specificity.keegan.st/) where you can check/learn how specificity works.

Comment: Actually it is `0,0,4,0`, `0,0,1,4`.

Comment: @HashemQolami - while that's the formal way of writing it, it makes more sense to me to think of them as numbers so that we can say that one is greater/less than the other

Comment: Yes, but note that `0,0,0,9` + `1` won't get `0,0,1,0` but `0,0,0,10` Hence better not to think them as *numbers*. An `#id` is  more specific than thousands of `.class`es :)